# NotSslRecordException exception thrown with Netty proxy server

Tags: ssl, netty

I am connecting my local netty server to a remote https server for proxying requests.

```
public class CustomInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private SslContext sslContext;


    @Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
        ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
        if (sslContext != null) {
            p.addLast(sslContext.newHandler(ch.alloc()));
        }
        p.addLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO));
        p.addLast(new HttpClientCodec());
        p.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(8*1024, true));
        p.addLast(new MyCustomHandler());
    }
}
```

Here is how I create ssLcontext bean

```
@Bean
    public SslContext sslContext(@Value("${tcp.ssl}") boolean ssl) throws SSLException, CertificateException {
        SslContext sslContext = null;
        if (ssl) {
            SelfSignedCertificate ssc = new SelfSignedCertificate();
            sslContext = SslContextBuilder.forServer(ssc.certificate(), ssc.privateKey()).build();
        }
        return sslContext;
    }
```

When I hit my localhost, it should proxy to backend. I get the following exception. However, if SSL is turned off and I connect to remote which is local server running on different port, it works fine

```
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: dsffddfs
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:459)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:647)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:547)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:501)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:461)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: thjhjhhj     at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1178)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1243)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:647)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:547)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:501)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:461)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: tyuuiiio
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:459)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:647)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:547)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:501)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:461)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: 678900
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1178)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1243)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)
    ... 16 more
```

**EDIT**

logs added

````````
X`20190423173352.427``40`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````eE````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0xc839c47e, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8080] READ: [id: 0xca2cb8c7, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56170]
X`20190423173352.427``40`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````fE````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0xc839c47e, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8080] READ COMPLETE
X`20190423173352.428``40`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````gE````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0xc839c47e, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8080] READ: [id: 0x08537ac8, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56171]
X`20190423173352.428``76`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````hE````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0xca2cb8c7, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56170] REGISTERED
X`20190423173352.428``40`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````iE````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0xc839c47e, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8080] READ COMPLETE
X`20190423173352.428``76`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````jE````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0xca2cb8c7, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56170] ACTIVE
X`20190423173352.429``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````kE````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x08537ac8, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56171] REGISTERED
X`20190423173352.429``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````lE````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x08537ac8, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56171] ACTIVE
X`20190423173352.442``76`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````mE````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0xca2cb8c7, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56170] READ COMPLETE
X`20190423173352.442``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````nE````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x08537ac8, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56171] READ: 294B

X`20190423173352.442``76`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````oE````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0xca2cb8c7, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56170] WRITE: 0B
X`20190423173352.442``76`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````pE````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0xca2cb8c7, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56170] FLUSH
X`20190423173352.443``76`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````qE````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0xca2cb8c7, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 ! R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56170] INACTIVE
X`20190423173352.443``76`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````rE````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0xca2cb8c7, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 ! R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56170] FLUSH
X`20190423173352.443``76`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````sE````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0xca2cb8c7, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 ! R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56170] CLOSE
X`20190423173352.443``76`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````tE````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0xca2cb8c7, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 ! R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56170] UNREGISTERED
X`20190423173352.450``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````uE````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x08537ac8, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56171] WRITE: 734B
X`20190423173352.452``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````vE````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x08537ac8, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56171] READ COMPLETE
X`20190423173352.452``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````wE````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x08537ac8, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56171] FLUSH
X`20190423173352.452``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````xE````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x08537ac8, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56171] WRITE: 0B
X`20190423173352.452``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````yE````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x08537ac8, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56171] FLUSH
X`20190423173352.453``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````zE````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x08537ac8, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56171] READ: 126B
X`20190423173352.456``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````0E````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x08537ac8, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56171] WRITE: 6B
X`20190423173352.457``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````1E````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x08537ac8, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56171] WRITE: 45B
X`20190423173352.457``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````2E````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x08537ac8, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56171] WRITE: 0B
X`20190423173352.457``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````3E````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x08537ac8, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56171] READ COMPLETE
X`20190423173352.457``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````4E````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x08537ac8, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56171] FLUSH
X`20190423173352.457``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````5E````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x08537ac8, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56171] WRITE: 0B
X`20190423173352.457``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````6E````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x08537ac8, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56171] WRITE: 0B
X`20190423173352.457``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````7E````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x08537ac8, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56171] FLUSH
X`20190423173352.458``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````8E````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x08537ac8, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56171] READ: 512B
X`20190423173352.458``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````9E````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x08537ac8, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56171] READ: 87B
X`20190423173352.460``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````-E````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x8c3b87f8] REGISTERED
X`20190423173352.460``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````_E````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x08537ac8, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56171] READ COMPLETE
X`20190423173352.460``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````AF````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x08537ac8, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56171] WRITE: 0B
X`20190423173352.461``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````BF````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x08537ac8, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56171] WRITE: 0B
X`20190423173352.461``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````CF````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x08537ac8, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56171] FLUSH
X`20190423173352.461``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````DF````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x8c3b87f8] CONNECT: dom.fbde.lol.hepd.com/122.126.80.1:443
X`20190423173352.483``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````EF````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x8c3b87f8, L:/10.3.49.27:56172 - R:dom.fbde.lol.hepd.com/122.126.80.1:443] WRITE: 0B
X`20190423173352.484``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````FF````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x8c3b87f8, L:/10.3.49.27:56172 - R:dom.fbde.lol.hepd.com/122.126.80.1:443] FLUSH
X`20190423173352.484``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````GF````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x8c3b87f8, L:/10.3.49.27:56172 - R:dom.fbde.lol.hepd.com/122.126.80.1:443] ACTIVE
X`20190423173402.488``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````HF````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x8c3b87f8, L:/10.3.49.27:56172 - R:dom.fbde.lol.hepd.com/122.126.80.1:443] FLUSH
X`20190423173402.488``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````IF````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x8c3b87f8, L:/10.3.49.27:56172 - R:dom.fbde.lol.hepd.com/122.126.80.1:443] CLOSE
X`20190423173402.489``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````JF````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x08537ac8, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56171] WRITE: 31B
X`20190423173402.489``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````KF````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x08537ac8, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56171] FLUSH
X`20190423173402.490``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````LF````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x08537ac8, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56171] CLOSE
X`20190423173402.490``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````MF````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x8c3b87f8, L:/10.3.49.27:56172 ! R:dom.fbde.lol.hepd.com/122.126.80.1:443] CLOSE
X`20190423173402.490``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````NF````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x8c3b87f8, L:/10.3.49.27:56172 ! R:dom.fbde.lol.hepd.com/122.126.80.1:443] INACTIVE
X`20190423173402.490``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````OF````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x8c3b87f8, L:/10.3.49.27:56172 ! R:dom.fbde.lol.hepd.com/122.126.80.1:443] UNREGISTERED
X`20190423173402.490``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````PF````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x08537ac8, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 ! R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56171] INACTIVE
X`20190423173402.491``77`````io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler```````QF````INFO`io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`[id: 0x08537ac8, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 ! R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56171] UNREGISTERED
````````

Answer (score 23):

When you receive an `NotSslRecordException` exception, you best starting point is the random blob of bytes following the error.

Your "blob" starts with the following bytes: `504f5354...`

After [converting](https://cryptii.com/pipes/hex-decoder) the hex data back to a String, you get `50` = `P`, `4f` = `O`, `53` = `S`, `54` = `T`, final result: `POST`

Since we now converted the start of the binary blob to a String, we now need to figure out what protocols use these "magic strings". We don't have to look far for  it, this is a `HTTP Request`, and you cannot use `HTTPS` to receive it.

The solution is simple, connect to your server using `https` instead of `http`:

https://localhost:8080/

Comment: I get this in the log.  `USER_EVENT: SslHandshakeCompletionEvent(javax.net.ssl.SSLException: handshake timed out)` and the request drops off

Comment: @brainstorm Place you logging handler before the ssl handler, and see if the server actually responds back to the client

Comment: I moved the logger, now I don't see handshake error but response is cut off still. I added logs to the post above

Comment: I kept debugger and found out that it is still handshake error, backEndHandler#ChannelRead is never invoked. I see error at `operationComplete` inside frontEndHandler.

Comment: Basically one is using plaintext encryption method and another is using TLS/SSL encryption. This is the reason for this Exception.